# How I can define universal numeric object with divisions support?

Tags: swift

I have a sample example:

```
struct Test<T: SignedNumeric & Comparable> {
    let n: T

    init(n: T) {
        self.n = n
    }
}

extension Test where T: BinaryInteger {
    func half() -> T {
       return self.n / 2
    }

    func printHalf() {
        print(self.half())
    }
}

extension Test where T: FloatingPoint {
    func half() -> T {
       return self.n / 2
    }

    func printHalf() {
        print(self.half())
    }
}

Test(n: 2).printHalf() // print "1"
Test(n: 2.2).printHalf()  // print "1.1
```

This code compiles and works. But I do not like:

1) I must additionally declare 2 extensions.

2) I have to duplicate `printHalf` method.

How correctly to implement this example? (just `is` inside the method?)